# How do I get Korean keyboard on Huawei Ascend G6

Tags: keyboard, 4.3-jelly-bean, input-methods, huawei

How do I install a Korean keyboard on the Huawei Ascend G6?

Comment: Which Android OS version does this device run? Have you tried seeing if Korean language is an option in built-in keyboard? Have you tried looking in Google Play Store for 3rd-party keyboards with Korean support?

Comment: @Chahk As the tag suggests it runs 4.3 jelly bean. In the end I installed "Google Korean keyboard", but I preferred to have the language within the original Google Keyboard as the other languages, especially because it looks like the Kor keyboard is more cpu intensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same way as on any other Android device:

1. go to the Android App Store of your choice (Google Play, AppBrain, whatever) and [search for "korean keyboard"](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=korean%20keyboard) (currently, 376 results)
2. install the one you find suiting your needs

There are several keyboards shipping with Korean language packs, so you might as well decide picking one of those. This might possibly even come with more functionality or better usability.

Not explicitly asked for, but it will probably be your next question: You might have to "activate" that "input method" for the keyboard to show up, or even make it the default one. This can be done in *Settings → Languages & Input* (by "Settings" I mean the Android settings).